# How to append 'string' data to local storage

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const MyForm = document.querySelector('#form');
const Fname = document.querySelector('#fname');
const Lname = document.querySelector('#lname');
const msg = document.querySelector('.msg');

MyForm.addEventListener('submit', OnSubmit);

function OnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (Fname.value === '' || Lname.value === '') {
        msg.innerHTML = 'Both fields are required to fill.'
        setTimeout(fadeaway, 2000);
        function fadeaway() {
            msg.remove();
        }
    }
    else {
        window.localStorage.setItem('fname', Fname.value);
        window.localStorage.setItem('lname', Lname.value);
        Fname.value = '';
        Lname.value = '';
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-div">
        <form id="form">
            <label>First name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
            <label>Last name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
            <div class="msg"></div>
            <div class="user">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I add a new 'Fname' and 'Lname', the previous data gets replaced with the new one. How can I add or append the data to the local storage.

I am new to JavaScript so make sure to describe the solution in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Any previous value will be reset when you set localStorage value. Therefore, you need to get the previous value in a variable, after that append the new value into that. Finally, update the localStorage value by that variable.

```
var firstName = window.localStorage.getItem('fname') || '';
firstName += Fname.value;

var lastName = window.localStorage.getItem('lname') || '';
lastName += Lname.value;

window.localStorage.setItem('fname', firstName);
window.localStorage.setItem('lname', lastName);
```

Comment: Can you explain this to me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a data in the local storage against a key will always overwrites the previous value. In your scenario what I suggest is just read the value from localstorage and append the new value and set the new value again to localstorage.

Example

```html
<div class="form-div">
    <form id="form">
        <label>First name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
        <label>Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
        <div class="msg"></div>
        <div class="user">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
const MyForm = document.querySelector('#form');
const Fname = document.querySelector('#fname');
const Lname = document.querySelector('#lname');
const msg = document.querySelector('.msg');

MyForm.addEventListener('submit', OnSubmit);

function OnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (Fname.value === '' || Lname.value === '') {
        msg.innerHTML = 'Both fields are required to fill.'
        setTimeout(fadeaway, 2000);
        function fadeaway() {
            msg.remove();
        }
    }
    else {
        const currentFName = window.localStorage.getItem('fname');
        const currentLName = window.localStorage.getItem('lname');
        window.localStorage.setItem('fname', `${currentFName};${Fname.value}`);
        window.localStorage.setItem('lname', `${currentLName};${Lname.value}`);
        Fname.value = '';
        Lname.value = '';
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct. You could write this logic in a separate helper function (storeOrAppendData) and call that to store or append it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-div">
        <form id="form">
            <label>First name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
            <label>Last name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
            <div class="msg"></div>
            <div class="user">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        const MyForm = document.querySelector('#form');
        const Fname = document.querySelector('#fname');
        const Lname = document.querySelector('#lname');
        const msg = document.querySelector('.msg');

        MyForm.addEventListener('submit', OnSubmit);

        function storeOrAppendData(key, value) {
            var temp = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
            if (temp) {
                temp += value;
            } else {
                temp = value;
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem(key, temp);
        }

        function OnSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (Fname.value === '' || Lname.value === '') {
                msg.innerHTML = 'Both fields are required to fill.'
                setTimeout(fadeaway, 2000);
                function fadeaway() {
                    msg.remove();
                }
            }
            else {
                storeOrAppendData('fname', Fname.value);
                storeOrAppendData('lname', Lname.value);
                Fname.value = '';
                Lname.value = '';
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```